# Dask DataFrame aggregate data based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a Dask DataFrame with a date-time column and other numeric columns. The successive entries in the DataFrame rows differ by a fixed time interval `t` mins. I want to aggregate the data hourly so that the average of the rows for the other columns data is computed for every hour. How can this be done, can `groupby` with date-time include specifying aggregation interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the [`resample`](https://www.google.com/search?q=dask+resample&oq=dask+resample) method.

In your case

```py
import dask

# Synthetic data
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

# Compute the average for each hour
df.resample('H').mean().compute()
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to add for the benefit of others who may need this, if we are reading the data frame externally, we can use `to_datetime()`, followed by `set_index()` and then` resample` as shown above.